# Programmatically modifying someones AppDelegate - categories, subclass?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c

I am working on a framework installer script. The script needs to modify the users AppDelegate file and inject a few lines of code at the beginning or end of the applicationDidFinishLaunching and applicationWillTerminatate methods.

Some options I've thought about:

- Parse the source code, and insert lines at correct positions. (Can be difficult to get right and work for everyone's code, just about equivalent to writing a compiler...)
- Subclass the AppDelegate file (is this possible?)
- Categories??

Which of these is the best option? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. First, if you add a subclass or category with PyObjC, that's PyObjC code, not ObjC code, so it's not going to affect the iOS app unless you actually distribute a PyObjC wrapper app that loads up the native app and modifies it in real-time (unless you're trying to do this for jailbroken phones via MobileSubstrate, in which case you might be able to inject your changes from outside).

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, it is an iOS obj-c project. I am writing the installer in python which will modify the source code (as text).

Comment: If you're trying to add source code for a subclass, that's a different story. You can do that, but you need to change their xcodeproj/makefile/whatever to build your new source, and you also need to change their source or nib to load your subclass instead of the base class, at which point you're back to "parse the source code".

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do. Parsing the xcodeproj is predictable and much easier then trying to modify source code that could take on any form depending on who is writing the program, etc.

Comment: Why can't you just get the developer to do it? You should be able to reduce what they need to do to a single line: `[AHThingy thingyWithAppDelegate:self]`, which can then hook in anything else it needs to do at runtime. As for the last comment, my point s that you still need to modify the source (or nib), because somewhere their code is instantiating a `MyAppDelegate`, and you need to make it instantiate the `GeneratedAppDelegateSubclass` instead.

Comment: One more thing: Normally a framework installer installs a framework to be used by 0 or more Xcode projects. Are you assuming that whatever project they have open and frontmost in Xcode at the moment is the only project they're ever going to build, and therefore hacking it up for them?

Comment: I am going to ask them to copy the script into their root project directory, and run it. it will recursively search for their xcodeproj file.

Comment: What kind of developer will have no problem copying a script and running it, but be incapable of adding a line to his source code? I'm not trying to disparage you; I'm trying to understand what you're actually trying to accomplish and why, so I can give an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I am currently considering:

1. Add NewAppDelegate.m/h file that subclasses AppDelegate.
2. This subclass, does what I want, and then calls the super methods.
3. Find/replace AppDelegate with NewAppDelegate.m.h in main.m

This seems pretty simple and robust. Thoughts on this? Will this work for all/most projects?

Comment: I thought about this as well but didn't post it as it seems like it would be bad implementation (not to mention possibly confusing for the end-user who didn't know about it). If you do go this route, just make sure you take care of rerouting **every* UIApplicationDelegate method there is.

Comment: Well, you're mixing up the class names and filenames—`main.m` isn't going to have any reference to `NewAppDelegate.m`. But also, this is pretty brittle—it will work for someone whose project was built with the new-app wizard in Xcode 4.2+ and who's never renamed anything, but what about someone whose delegate is named `MyAppDelegate`, or who's using one of those portability libraries that creates a `FooAppDelegate` inside `Foo.framework`?

Comment: @mbuc91: If you subclass, you don't need to reroute everything; you just inherit all of the methods from the base class that you haven't redefined.

Comment: You're right; I confused subclassing and importing, somehow. Anyway, @Andy, still be sure to add a comment or something in the new file to remind the end user that it is subclassing their previous file.

Comment: I concede that it may not work for people who do not have a standard main.m file. But for those that do (which I would guess is the majority of developers.. feel free to lmk if you disagree): it will contain a call to whatever their AppDelegate is called (i.e if they've subclassed it). You could capture this, subclass it, etc.

@mbuc91 as mentioned, you don't need to override all default methods, just the ones you want to change functionality for. Plus, I would argue that it is cleaner because the framework code is self contained.

Comment: @AndyHin: Are you trying to make this work for 99.9% of your customers, or is working for 80% and asking the other 20% to do it manually a reasonable goal here? Because if it's the latter, then yes, you can probably assume some structure in `main.m` and in their file and class naming, because there's a fallback for when your assumptions fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to make this something that modifies the `AppDelegate` with no intervention at all from the developer, and you can modify the xcodeproj and the nib but not the source, there is a way to do it.

First, make sure your classes get compiled in, and an instance of your class gets created in the nib.

Now, here's what you do:

- Define a `-[AHHackClass applicationDidFinishLaunching]` method that does your extra stuff, then calls the `[self originalApplicationDidFinishLaunching]`.
- In `-[AHHackClass awakeFromNib:]`, use objc runtime calls to copy the `-[AHHackClass applicationDidFinishLaunching]` method to the application delegate as `-[originalApplicationDidFinishLaunching]`, then use method swizzling to swap the two methods' implementations.
- Do the same to swizzle `applicationWillTerminate`.

See [`JRSwizzle`](https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle) for some code that makes the method swizzling much easier, and [`MethodSwizzling` at CocoaDev](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling) for some background.

However, there may be a much easier way to do this: Does your extra stuff really need to be called from the app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and `applicationWillTerminate` methods? Can't you just set up to listen for notifications in your `awakeFromNib` and handle things there?

And if, for some reason, you can't do that, can you just put a line in the instructions to the developer to call your method from their `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method?

Comment: I am looking at possibly using swizzling. Any advantage over my answer?

Comment: If you just want to get started with swizzling and mess around with it, you could use [Injection for Xcode](http://injectionforxcode.com).

Comment: The advantage of swizzling over your answer is that you don't need to make any assumptions about what their delegate is called, what its source looks like (or where it is), etc. At runtime, their delegate class is guaranteed to be `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] class]`.

Comment: The advantage of just using notifications and not hooking their code at all is that it's much less hacky—easier to read, write, and debug; easier to explain to your users; unlikely to conflict with other frameworks; etc.